# Visual Studio 2012 - "Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol" when attempting to include .lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, phash

I am trying to include a `.lib` file in my Visual Studio 2012 C++ project. The library is the pHash project to be specific. I have added the header file for the project to `Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Includes` and the `.lib` file's folder to `Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories`. `pHash.lib` has been added to the list of dependencies in`Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`. But even though I have done all of this I still get this error when trying to use the libraries: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl ph_dct_imagehash(char const *,unsigned __int64 &)" (?ph_dct_imagehash@@YAHPBDAA_K@Z) referenced in function _main`.

My code looks as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pHash.h"

using namespace std;

int ph_dct_imagehash(const char *file, ulong64 &hash);

int main()
{
   ulong64 tmp = 0;
   ulong64 &hash = tmp;
   const char *file = "C:\\users\\user\\desktop\\img1.jpg";

   ph_dct_imagehash(file, hash);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try #include <pHash.p> now you've been to the trouble of setting the include path properly. (note <> not "")

Comment: Are you building the lib as part of the solution, or adding a pre-built lib ?

Comment: @Kindread I'm adding a pre-built lib. (Actually I built the lib myself from the pHash project files)

Comment: @doctorlove, you have a typo which is confusing OP!

Comment: Sorry world - I meant #include <pHash.h>, not .p

Comment: did you get this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

You will not need the prototype

```
int ph_dct_imagehash(const char *file, ulong64 &hash);
```

after including `pHash.h` as the latter will declare the functions for you.

Remove that line and examine any compiler error (which, if any, will be something on the lines of not being able to find the function `ph_dct_imagehash`). Perhaps you'll need to prefix with a correct namespace:

```
somephashnamespace::ph_dct_imagehash(file, hash);
```

Comment: I suspect this is a C library so won't have a namespace - it will be interesting to see what happens when the prototype gets removed.

Comment: Removing the prototype just makes the function call undefined.

Comment: @user1049697, I was counting on that. Read the docs to see how you should properly include ph_dct_imagehash and what namespace it's in, if any.

Comment: @Bathsheba The documentation doesn't provide any more info than the prototype and parameters. I don't think it's in a namespace either.

Comment: @user1049697; do a global search for the ph_dct_imagehash and see what header it's in. Include that.

Comment: @Bathsheba It is in the `pHash.h` header which is already included.

Comment: @user1049697; could you tell me the actual prototype? Either in comment or amend the question text?

Comment: @Bathsheba The prototype from the headerfile is int ph_dct_imagehash(const char* file,ulong64 &hash);

Comment: @user1049697; now it's time to implement doctorlove's suggestion. Are you sure the function is not #ifdef'd out in the include file?

Comment: @Bathsheba There are some #ifdefs in the include. Doing as Doctorlove suggests and including <pHash.p> doesn't help since it doesn't exist.

Comment: @user1049697: doctorlove has a typo. He meant <pHash.h>

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah, I figured as much so I tried <pHash.h> as well. :) But it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Does it make some difference? How is ulong64 defined?

Comment: @doctorlove It doesn't make any difference on the output. ulong64 is defined as follows: typedef unsigned long long ulong64;